# How to pass method name dynamically in java

Tags: java, reflection

I have an Class like as follows

```
public class Test
{
     private Long id;
     private Long locationId;
     private Long anotherId;

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public Long getLocationId() {
    return locationId;
}


public void setLocationId(Long locationId) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
}


public Long getAnotherId() {
    return anotherId;
}


public void setAnotherId(Long anotherId) {
    this.anotherId = anotherId;
}
}
```

I have used  following methods in various places to find the matched object by using id,locationId or anotherId

```
public Test getMatchedObject(List<Test> list,Long id )
{

          for(Test vo : list)
                if(vo.getId() != null && vo.getId().longValue() == id.longValue())
                return vo;
}

public Test getMatchedLocationVO(List<Test> list,Long locationId )
{

          for(Test vo : list)
                if(vo.getLocationId() != null && vo.getLocationId().longValue() == locationId.longValue())
                return vo;
}

public Test getMatchedAnotherVO(List<Test> list,Long anotherId )
{

          for(Test vo : list)
                if(vo.getAnotherId() != null && vo.getAnotherId().longValue() == anotherId.longValue())
                return vo;
}
```

I used different method for each parameter to find out the object.Is there any way i can pass method name dynamically?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: sounds like reflection

Comment: @JigarJoshi i dont have knowledge on that.Can u give me an example or can u suggest me

Comment: @PSR Something like [Object callMethod((Object receiver,
      String methodName, Object... parameters)](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html)?

Comment: Or you can create an interface with a getId method that accepts the Test object as parameter and returns the appropriate id value in the implementing class. You can also use an abstract class to achieve it.

Comment: @RebeccaAbriam i did't understand your statement.Can u explain

Comment: @PSR i posted an answer to illustrate my idea..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use reflection to do this.

`import java.lang.reflect.*;`

`Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);`

then invoke it with `method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2);`

This is somewhat similar to the way call works in javascript (if you're familiar with that), except instead of passing the context, you're passing the object and a reference to it's method.

Comment: *obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, arg1Class)

ex. String.class

Comment: using this with Lombok throws No Such Method Exception when used for a setter method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reflection, but it's probably not the best solution to your original problem as reflection is meant for use by programming tools. You should look into using other tools, like polymorphism and inheritence, that can provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Although you are calling methods dynamically and it seems like reflection, but as far as I see, you are calling accessors and nested accessors, which leads to use [Java Introspection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) API.

It supports Java Bean API, and accessors/mutators and nested accessors/mutators easily.

There are some other libraries which simplify this too, such as [Apache BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/beanutils/), and [BeanWrapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html?is-external=true) class by Spring.

Answer (score 1):

By using [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) API you can do it
[see this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution using interface.. Hope you get the idea.. Code doesn't necessarily compiles. Apologies for formatting as this is entered only in iPad.

```
public interface IdMatcher{
  Long id;
  public boolean matches(Test obj);
}
```

Concrete class:

```
public class LocationIdMatcher implements IdMatcher() {
  public LocationIdMatcher(id) {
  this.id = id;
}
public boolean matches(Test obj) {
   if (obj.getLocationId() == this.id)
    return true;
   }
}
```

getMatchedVO updated:

```
public Test getMatchedVO(List<Test> list, IdMatcher idMatcher) {
  for(Test vo: list) {
   if(idMatcher.matches(vo) {
     return vo;
   }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
Test vo = getMatchedVO(list, new LocationIdMatcher(locationId));
```