# Run a java method by passing class name and method name as parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that executes a particular method when the class name and method name are passed as String parameter to the caller. Consider the code below. I have a class CarBean :

```
public class CarBean {

    private String brand;
    private String color;

    /**
     * @return the brand
     */
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    /**
     * @param the brand to set
     */
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand= brand;
    }

    /**
     * @return the color
     */
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * @param the color to set
     */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color= color;
    }

}
```

Now I want to run this via a method as below :

```
runTheMehod("CarBean","getColor");
```

The implementation of runTheMethod would be like this :

```
public runTheMethod(String className, String methodName){
try {
            Object carObj = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            //What to do now???
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I can get an object using the class name. Now I need to cast it to a CarBean object and then I can run its method. So wondering how to cast it at runtime as the classname would be different for each call. Also, can I check whether the class has specific method before I try call it?

Any suggestion on the problem would be appreciated. Also, I'm all ears to know if there is a better approach to do this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Comment: Are you sure you want to instantiate a fresh object of that type? e.g. `runTheMethod(Object instance, String methodName)` would work too and leave it up to you to create objects of that type.

Comment: @zapl Yes I am getting the class name in string format

Comment: It is doable with Java Reflection, but you should think about a better design before trying that solution.

Comment: @Dici I am open to any suggestion that can improve the design

Comment: @GV with your example I don't see how using reflection can be simpler than not using it. I cannot propose another design since I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: @GV Check out [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

Comment: so basically I'll be reading className and methodname from and excel file or database. So it'll be in string format and not object. Then I will be running them one by one.

Comment: Since you're always creating a new object it will never have a color, or brand, or anything else, so you could simply replace all of your code with `return null`. This has the advantage of being significantly faster than using reflection.

Comment: @DavidConrad I understand that, but I'll be using it for other methods at Action/Service/DAO layers which will return values according to inputs provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass method name dynamically in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419511/how-to-pass-method-name-dynamically-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What to do now???

You can now call the method on your `carObj` like this:

```
Method method = carObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
method.invoke(carObj);
```

See also:

[Method.invoke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This works well. I have one more question: If I want to extend the implementation, I pass the return value also as input and compare it, then I'll either need to cast it or implement the hashCode for CarBean (or every class I pass). Any suggestion on that ? - public runTheMethod(String className, String methodName, Object returnValue)

Comment: Yes, you need to do some casts then or ... just compare them (the `returnValue` passed in and the actual returned value) as `Object`s by using their `equals` method (but be careful with `null` in case one or both of them are `null`).

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is call a method by name, you don't need to cast it to anything. It is sufficient to use the `Object` with further reflection.

See [`Class.getDeclaredMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...)), as in:

```
Object carObj = ...;
Method method = carObj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, ...);
Object retObj = method.invoke(carObj, ...);
```

Note that we don't care what type `carObj` actually is, although if you wanted to check you could always use `instanceof` or `Class.isAssignableFrom` or `Class.isInstance`.

It is a bit weird, though, that you are instantiating a new object then calling one of its methods all in one go. That object goes away once your `runTheMethod` returns.

---

By the way, it looks like you're just trying to get and set bean properties. You might want to have a look at [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) instead, then your example becomes simply:

```
CarBean bean = ...;
String color = (String)PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(bean, "color"); // calls getter.
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I used CarBean as an example but it's not limited to a Java bean. I might have to run this for other methods as in Action/Service/DAO layers.

Comment: Careful with `getDeclaredMethod` vs `getMethod`, first just returns methods (re)defined in this the class - inherited methods are not found, latter just public methods: http://ideone.com/veKNyU

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you *really* need to do this. I suspect you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your question is somewhat similar to asking whether Java has an `eval` function and [the correct answer is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27396372/545127):

First ask yourself, where did these `String` come from? Did another part of your program generate them, or was it input provided by the user?

- **Another part of my program generated it**: so, you want one part of your program to decide the kind of operation to perform, but not perform the operation, and a second part that performs the chosen operation. Instead of generating and then evaluating `String`s, use the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern, as appropriate for your particular case.
- **It is user input**: the user could input *anything*, including class and method names that, when executed, could cause your program to misbehave, crash, expose information that should be secret, damage persistent information (such as the content of a database), and other such nastiness. The only way to prevent that would be to parse the `String`s and then either immediately execute the method on a successful parse, or have the parser create a Command object for later execution.