# Compare the return value of a method when expected return type and return value are passed as string parameters

Tags: java

To give a little background on what I am trying to do, please refer my previous question :

[Run a java method by passing class name and method name as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919701/run-a-java-method-by-passing-class-name-and-method-name-as-parameter)

So basically I am trying to call a method and test its return value. I'll read the following parameters from an xml or database : The method class,name,parameters and return value.
Then I'll execute the method and compare the output.

The code looks like this as of now :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        runTheMethod("CarBean","getColor","java.lang.String","Red");
    }

    public static void runTheMethod(String className, String methodName, String expectedReturnType, Object expectedReturnValue){
        try {
            Object classObj = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            Method method = classObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
            Object returnVal = method.invoke(classObj);
            if(expectedReturnValue.getClass().getName().equals(expectedReturnType)){
// This is the problem portion
                System.out.println("Test passed : " + expectedReturnValue.equals(returnVal));
            }else{ 
                System.out.println("Expected return object type does not match actual return object type");
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Carbean is a user defined pojo :

```
public class CarBean {

    private String brand;
    private String color = "Red";

    public CarBean (){
    }

    public CarBean (String brand, String color){
        this.brand= brand;
        this.color= color;
    }

    /**
     * @return the brand
     */
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    /**
     * @param the brand to set
     */
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand= brand;
    }

    /**
     * @return the color
     */
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * @param the color to set
     */
    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color= color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o == null)               
            return false;
        if(!(o instanceof CarBean))
            return false;

        CarBean other = (CarBean) o;
        if(this.brand!=null && this.color!=null){
            if(this.brand.equals(other.brand) && this.color.equals(other.color))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }else{
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = 31 * hash + this.brand.hashCode();
        hash = 31 * hash + this.color.hashCode();
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Now this works fine for the current code - return type is String and I can compare using equals.
But what if the method returns a BigDecimal or List? Is there a generic way I can compare multiple object types?

I am assuming that for a user defined java beans (pojo) I can override the equals() and hashcode() to compare it.  Referring my blog for details:
http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2014/10/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-for-pojo.html

Any further suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can use `equals`. I guess I don't really understand what the problem is. Though your implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` in `CarBean` is arguably incorrect due to mishandling of null instance fields.

Comment: @Radiodef see the return type could be anything. It might not override equals all the time. Also, what wrong do you see with handling of null fields?

Comment: I am basically trying to make a generic code. It will execute a method and compare the return value with the expected value. The problem being, I'll run the same code for every method and return types would be different. So I am trying to make a code which can compare any return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as creating objects from string values in your XML file. You basically already know how to do this. You just need to put the class name for the return type in the XML file. Then you can create your expected return value. For example:

```
Object newInstance(String cls, String arg) throws LotsOfExceptions {
    return Class.forName(cls).getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(arg);
}

Object obj = newInstance("java.math.BigInteger", "1000");
```

So you can create a BigInteger from an XML file. If you want to create objects that do not define String constructors then you need to store some other information in the file that tells your program how to turn it in to an object. Maybe you should look in to abstract factory patterns. Another (more complicated) scheme would be to serialialize an object, then encode the bytes as base 64 so you can store it as text.

And before I go any further, I want to point out that running arbitrary Java commands from text input is unsafe. It would be safer if you were keeping a whitelist of allowed classes so that classes like `System` and `File` were off limits. It's OK to just experiment with this yourself, but in practice this is **very unstable** unless you are taking precautions.

On the subject of comparisons, you need to understand that equality is a concept that differs greatly from type to type. In general `equals` is a correct way to compare, because it is the equality that a class has defined for itself. If a class does not override `equals`, then it does not have a concept of value equality.

There are other ways to compare, for example, you could use reflection to compare two object's internal states.

Using reflection has issues though:

- It is actually pretty complicated to write yourself.
- Objects that define value equality through `equals` may have transient internal state that is deliberately not compared. So if we compare with reflection we are disregarding the value equality that a class may have defined. (And you may get unexpected results. For example, [some versions of `String` calculate `hashCode` lazily](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29).)

You might see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449001/2891664) for a few libraries that do a reflection comparison already.

Here is a simple example of the kind of thing that is possible to do:

```
boolean publicallyEqual(Object a, Object b) throws IllegalAccessException {
    if(a.getClass() != b.getClass())
        return false;

    for(Field f : a.getClass().getFields()) {
        Object af = f.get(a);
        Object bf = f.get(b);
        if(af == null ? bf != null : !af.equals(bf))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

That example compares public fields by `equals`, so it works for very simple objects (like a `java.awt.Point`). More complicated routines would compare the fields recursively and account for arrays.

Reflection could be an appropriate approach for something like unit testing of deserialization, where an object maybe doesn't define a value equality but we want to see if it got deserialized with a correct state.

---

The problem with your `equals` and `hashCode` is that:

- Your `equals` considers an object not equal to any other object if their `brand` or `color` field is null.

```
if(this.brand!=null && this.color!=null){
    ...
}else{
    return false;
}
```

It means that a `CarBean(null, null)` is not equal to a `CarBean(null, null)`. Generally `equals` doesn't exhibit this type of behavior. For example, even a NaN equals another NaN by [`Double#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) comparison.

- Your `hashCode` throws a NullPointerException if `brand` or `color` is null.

The corrected implementations would be as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(!(o instanceof CarBean)) // also this already evaluates
        return false;           // to false if o is null

    CarBean other = (CarBean) o;
    if(brand == null ? other.brand != null : !brand.equals(other.brand))
        return false;
    if(color == null ? other.color != null : !color.equals(other.color))
        return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash = 31 * hash + (brand == null ? 0 : brand.hashCode());
    hash = 31 * hash + (color == null ? 0 : color.hashCode());
    return hash;
}
```

(And if null is an invalid state, then the constructors and setters should throw exceptions rather than letting the error trickle to your `equals` and `hashCode`.)

Answer (score 1):

If your class implements `Comparable`, you can add a `public int compareTo(Object o)` function.

Then you can call it using `int result = yourObject.compareTo(anotherObject);`

But keep in mind that the function return an int. < 0 if yourObject is smaller 0 if it's equal and > 0 if it's greater.

You can compare your object to different objects using `instanceOf` inside `compareTo(Object o)` but you need to specify how the comparison should be handled with a specific object, Java will not guess for you

Answer (score 1):

So I see two points here.

1. When two Java objects are considered equal?
   Let o1 and o2 be objects. They are equal if and only if o1.equals(o2) and o2.equals(o1);
   So you can just use equals method ( with respect to null references). (Lists and BigDecimals both have overriden equals method)
2. That if some POJO doesn't override equals?
   Well you can think that two objects are equal if they belongs to same class and values returned from all getters are equals. Thats a dangerous road to take. But if you really want to do it [java.beans](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/package-summary.html) package can help you.

Answer (score 1):

All java classes are descendant of the Object class. The Javadoc of Object class defines the general contract for methods `equal` and `hashcode`. Extracts :

- The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references

  - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
  - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
  - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
  - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
  - For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.
- The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).
- Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

These are general java requirements, so you can safely assume that all classes you test respect them. The good part if that Java containers or arrays(*) implement equality in a sense that is coherent with the equality of their elements.

EDIT :

(*) For arrays equality, you will have to use `Arrays.equals()` - thanks to Nikolay Ivanov for noting it

Comment: You totally right, except for arrays part. For proper equality we must use Arrays.equals().

Comment: @NikolayIvanov : Thanks for noting it ! Post edited.