# Java 8: Method as parameter with Lambda reference

Tags: java, lambda

I have scanned serveral links but didn't find an easy solution for Java 8 Lambda expression. The most useful hint I've found was on [Java 8 Lambdas](http://www.studytrails.com/java/java8/Java8_Lambdas_FunctionalProgramming/) but did NOT really satisfy my interest.

I want to achieve a reoccuring pattern in my code:

```
List<?> content=retrieveContent(strFilter);
if (!content.isEmpty())
    setField1(content.get(0));
```

and I would like to have it simple as

`retrieveContent(strFilter, this::setField1)` but somehow I don't get syntax properly - especially for the method. I can do it as a String and call [if via method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26919701/run-a-java-method-by-passing-class-name-and-method-name-as-parameter), but than its prone to typos... Any other ideas?

Comment: How do you know setField1() method is available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), which will work as long as you fill in the generics with a value other than `<?>`.

For example:

```
private List<Object> retrieveContent(String strFilter, Consumer<Object> firstItemConsumer) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Build the return...

    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
        firstItemConsumer.accept(list.get(0));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Can then be called with:

```
List<Object> content = retrieveContent(strFilter, this::setField1);
```

Comment: And of course, instead of `<Object>`, one could reference a type parameter of the host class, or a type parameter of the method if the method were made generic.

Comment: Thx, this works basically the way as expected :-) Except that JPA does NOT like Lambda-stuff (at least for EclipseLink 2.5x)